# Fubini's theorem for a measure on product space, which is not a product of measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, product-space

Let $X,Y$ be some nice measurable spaces (I'm interested in $[0,1]$ so we can assume compact, etc.). Let $\mu$ be a measure on $X\times Y$ (again, assume it's a nice probability measure, or even something strong if needed).

Define $\mu_1(A)=\mu(A\times Y)$ and reps. $\mu_2$.

I imagine that Fubini's theorem should hold, meaning that:
$\mu(A)=\int\mu_1(A^y)d\mu_2(y)$? **is that necessarily true?**

Could you give some type of conditions under which it is true?

If I were to prove it, I would probably go to the original proof of Fubini and try to manipulate it, although it would be a long job.

A type of conditions I'm okay with allowing $\mu$ to have:
Assume $\mu_1$ is invariant under $x\to(x+a) \operatorname{mod}  1$for all $a$ (or just assume it's Lebesgue!!), and $\mu$ is invariant under $(x,y)\to(x,y+a)\mod 1$ for all $a$ (in particular $\mu_2$ is also Lebesgue, but we have something strong too). Could you deduce that Fubini holds in the manner that I suggested? (which would give the desired $\mu$ is Lebesgue)

Comment: Various versions of Fubini's theorem can be found here: p. 219 and successives https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf

Comment: Again, the answer to your question depends on the definition of "nice."

Comment: @Math1000 Is that so bad that it depends on the definition of nice? ya, it's a general question.

If it is, lets assume something really strong relatively to what I'm trying to deduce: Assume $\mu_1$ is invariant under $x\to x+a \mod 1$ for all  $a$ (i.e. it's lebesgue!!), and $\mu$ is invariant under $(x,y)\to (x,y+a)\mod1$ for all $a$ (in particular $\mu_2$ is also lebesgue, but we have something strong too). Could you deduce that fubini holds in the manner that I suggested? (which would mean $\mu$ is lebesgue)

Comment: @b00nheT thanks, but I could not find what I wanted there

Answer (score 2):

(Focusing on the case $X=Y=[0,1]$ with Borel sets.)

**1.** A probability measure on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ admits a *disintegration*
$$
\mu(A)=\int_{[0,1]}\mu_1(dx)K(x,A),\qquad A\in\mathcal B([0,1]^2),
$$
with $K$ a *kernel* such that $x\mapsto K(x,A)$ is Borel measurable for each $A\in \mathcal B([0,1]^2$ and $A\mapsto K(x,A)$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]^2$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. Moreover, $K$ can be chosen so that $\mu_1\{x:K(x,x\times[0,1])=1)=1$. The kernel $K$ is as unique as you could reasonably wish for: If $K'$ is another kernel with the properties listed above, then $\mu_1(x:K(x,\cdot)\not=K'(x,\cdot))=0$.

Of course, $\mu$ is the product of its marginals ($\mu=\mu_1\otimes\mu_2$) if and only if $K(x,A)=\mu_2(A_x)$ for $\mu_1$-a.e. $x\in[0,1]$.

(An analogous disintegration with respect to the second marginal is also available.)

**2.** The special case raised in your comment can be shown to hold using disintegration. A direct argument is also available. Thus, suppose that $\mu_1$ in invariant under translations mod 1, and that $\mu$ is invariant under "vertical" translations mod 1.
As you note, we then have $\mu_1=\lambda$ (Lebesgue measure). Let $F:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be Borel measurable and bounded. Then (additions below understood to be modulo  1)
$$
\int_{[0,1]^2}F\,d\mu=\int_{[0,1]^2}F(x,y+a)\,\mu(dx,dy).
$$
Now integrate both sides of this with respect to $a\in[0,1]$, using Fubini
$$
\int_{[0,1]^2}F\,d\mu=\int_{[0,1]^2}G(x)\mu(dx,dy)=\int_{0,1]}G(x)\mu_1(dx)=\int_0^1 G(x)\,dx.
$$
here $G(x)=\int_0^1 F(x,y+a)\,da = \int_0^1 F(x,y)\,dy$. It follows that 
$$
\int_{[0,1]^2}F\,d\mu=\int_0^1 \left[\int_0^1 F(x,y)\,dy\right]\,dx.
$$
That is, $\mu$ is $\lambda\otimes\lambda$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly the OP's notation, i.e. $\mu_1 = {p_1}_* \mu$ and $\mu_2 = {p_2}_* \mu$, with $p_1$ and $p_2$ the coordinate projections? If so, it is not true, in general, that $\mu = \mu_1 \otimes \mu_2$. In particular, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^2$, then what the OP wants is not true.

Comment: @Alex M.: Yes, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the images of $\mu$ under the coordinate projections. And you are correct that $\mu_1\otimes\mu_2$ does not always coincide with $\mu$. It does if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^2$, for then $\mu_j$ are also Lebesgue measure (on $[0,1]$). It also does, as I have indicated, when $\mu_1$ and $\mu$ are translation invariant as the OP indicates.